# Will Configuring Two DNS Servers (External and Local) Work as Split DNS?

Tags: networking, router, dns

I want to reach a local server, `ServerA`, using a consistent hostname whether I am on the same network (LAN) or a public network (WAN).

`ServerA` is on a local network with some ports accessible externally through port forwarding.

My router does not support hairpin NATs, so I am unable to reach the device using the external hostname of my router and forwarded ports when I am on my local network.

This brings me to split-horizon DNS.

However, I do not want to have to run my own public DNS server.

I see on my phone (the only device which I will use to reach `SeverA`) that I can use multiple DNS servers.

If I have to run my own DNS server to do this could I:

- Enter it as the first DNS server option
- Enter current DNS sever as the second option

My thinking is that when I am on my local network the first DNS server will be used and when I am not the second DNS server will be used.

**Will this work?**

I think that DNS records are cached which means when I leave my local network the local hostname might still resolve to the machine pointed to by my first, local DNS server.

**Is this correct?**

**If so, are there any ways to make a server reachable on local and external networks on a router that does not support hairpin NATs other than configuring split DNS, making my DNS sever publicly available and using all the time?**

Comment: No, adding multiple DNS servers to a device will not (in most cases) cause it to use both, or be selective about which one it is using at a given time. most network stacks will use the first one until it presents actual errors (like server unreachable; not just NX domain responses) and then it will fall back to using the second one. generally split horizon allows the DNS servers passed out by the networks DHCP service to control which DNS server is being used based on what network you are connected to.

Comment: why do you want your own public DNS server? there are definitely cases where organizations will want to do that, but for home networking usually a public registrar that carries your domain is sufficient, especially if you are doing DDNS. if you were to register a domain and let a host carry it for you using your public IP, you could set up an internal DNS server on your network, configure it with your zone and internal IPs, and forwarders that point to upstream DNS severs to resolve other domains. then you just set your DHCP server to pass your internals clients the internal DNS name.

Comment: @FrankThomas if I do that I think there will be a problem if I use a mobile device and take it out of my home and use it on an external network. The goal is to have one hostname work for internal and external networks.

Comment: you can have one hostname, but it has to be hosted on two servers, one internal and one external. the internal name will indicate the servers local IP, and the external one (either one you host or one hosted by the registrar) indictates your public IP. this is called Split-horizon DNS resolution, where LAN clients get one version of the zone, and clients on any other network get the external version of the zone,

Comment: What do you mean "it has to be hosted on two servers"?
The example would be that I want to ssh into a machine and I want to use the same hostname (e.g. server1.example.com) whether I am on the internal or external network.

Comment: since you said your gateway router does not support hairpin, you can't just use 1 IP address for your server both inside and out. you need the external clients to get the public IP address, and the LAN clients to get the LAN IP address for the server. you do that by hosting two zones for your domain, one that has names bound to your public IP, and one that has names bound to the LAN IP. usually this is done by hosting a DNS server on the LAN that carries the LAN version of the zone which your clients point to, and by hosting your public DNS records on the Internet.

Comment: So short answer, you need a DNS server on your LAN (it need not be an actual server, lots of NASs and Routers will host a zone for you) configured to forward unresolved requests up to a public DNS server on the Internet. your clients will point to this server for all lookups, and if you lookup a LAN system you will get a LAN IP for it. if you lookup another domain however, it will send your queries out to the internet to be resolved. that way you are only connecting to one DNS server, but that server will resolve all requests internal and external (with assistance from upstream DNS).

Comment: @FrankThomas if I take a device (like my phone) and I bring it from the LAN to the WAN, does it automatically use whichevery DNS record corresponds to the network? In other words, if I go to example.com on my LAN and example.com on a WAN, do devices use different DNS records or do they cache it and use the same one?

Comment: yes, probably. DNS is set by the network connection, on wifi via dhcp. I don't honestly know what autoconfiguration protocols are used in 4G/5G network connection setup, but your cell radios are going to have a different network configuration than your wifi (and in fact each wifi you connect to will supply its own DNS server config), and that configuration will include DNS settings. now that said caching is out of your control, so there is room for your milage to vary. you may have to reload a page or restart an app if you leave the house with it running. there is nothing to do about it.